# Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1

Tags: reactjs, netlify

im trying to deploy website on netlify but some problems occur. This is a log:

```
11:37:14 AM: Build ready to start
11:37:15 AM: build-image version: 9e0f207a27642d0115b1ca97cd5e8cebbe492f63
11:37:15 AM: build-image tag: v3.3.2
11:37:15 AM: buildbot version: ef8d0929ed0baabafd8bbb7d0b021e1fc24180c0
11:37:16 AM: Fetching cached dependencies
11:37:16 AM: Failed to fetch cache, continuing with build
11:37:16 AM: Starting to prepare the repo for build
11:37:16 AM: No cached dependencies found. Cloning fresh repo
11:37:16 AM: git clone https://github.com/ocebeki/transmess
11:37:18 AM: Preparing Git Reference refs/heads/master
11:37:19 AM: Starting build script
11:37:19 AM: Installing dependencies
11:37:20 AM: Downloading and installing node v10.16.0...
11:37:20 AM: Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.16.0/node-v10.16.0-linux-x64.tar.xz...
11:37:21 AM: 
########################
11:37:21 AM:  34.2%
11:37:21 AM: 
########################################################
11:37:21 AM: ################ 100.0%
11:37:21 AM: Computing checksum with sha256sum
11:37:21 AM: Checksums matched!
11:37:23 AM: Now using node v10.16.0 (npm v6.9.0)
11:37:23 AM: Attempting ruby version 2.6.2, read from environment
11:37:25 AM: Using ruby version 2.6.2
11:37:25 AM: Using PHP version 5.6
11:37:25 AM: Started restoring cached node modules
11:37:25 AM: Finished restoring cached node modules
11:37:25 AM: Installing NPM modules using NPM version 6.9.0
11:37:28 AM: npm
11:37:28 AM: ERR!
11:37:28 AM: failed during stage 'building site': Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
11:37:28 AM:  code EINVALIDTAGNAME
11:37:28 AM: npm
11:37:28 AM: ERR! Invalid tag name "^4.12.": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
```

I tried build on the local env and then deploy on netlify  but didn't work neither.
Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the issue in the `package.json` for the invalid tag in one of your dependencies:

```
    "node-sass": "^4.12.",
```

should be a valid form (missing):

```
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
```